# How to make a concentric pie chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2011

I'd like to make a chart (preferably on its own sheet) that is a combination of a regular pie and a doughnut. The regular pie sits in the middle and the doughnut surrounds it.

I have seen those before, but I fail to see the option in Excel. I use Excel for Mac 2011 and/or Excel for Mac (Preview).

Assuming that the standard option is not there, what would be the best way to go about making it anyway?

This is an attempt that (unfortunately) is not on its own sheet (because it is one chart on top of another):

[image]

Comment: Excel pie charts are fairly limited in terms of their extensibility.   You can do the "slice as new pie cutout" option but that's about it.  If you're getting close with your current approach, I'd run with it. Any reason you need the chart as its own worksheet?

Comment: @Byron Basically, I'd like to make sure that it has the exact same formatting (size, to start) as my other charts (before I copy-paste them into PowerPoint). I might pursue having both charts on separate sheets of their own, and then copy-paste both of them on top of each other in PowerPoint. It would be twice the work (which would have to be repeated ad nauseam).

Comment: Gotcha.  One option to get the sizes all the same is to use VBA to set all the `Width` and `Height` values equal to common ones.  This is very easy macro to write (couple of loops
).  Can you use a screenshot instead of a live chart?  If not, I think you are at the limits of Excel's charting.

Comment: You can also add a chart as an object into a chart sheet.  It would still be 2 stacked charts, but it gets closer to what you want.  Keeping them properly stacked would be the main issue.

Comment: @gtwebb I'm not sure about the _keeping_, but accidentally Excel put the object right on the intended spot with exactly the right sizing. (Although I had to change to order. First it was doughnut on top of pie. Now it is (automagically downsized) pie on top of doughnut... Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it is a small pie on top of a larger pie now. Looks great.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat: These two pages should be of help: [1](http://peltiertech.com/donut-pie-combination/), [2](http://www.andypope.info/charts/pies.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel can do this in a single chart (if you really want it too, that's up to you). It's actually pretty easy:

1. Create a doughnut chart.
2. Add both series (as in you sample, but you can have multiple rings).
3. Adjust your series so that the your inside pie chart is Series 1.
4. Change Series 1 chart type to Pie Chart.
5. Format your Doughnut Chart Hole Size to 50% (or whatever suits).
6. Format other colors and borders to suit.

Here's a sample

[image: PieDoughnut]

And, since it's a single chart, you can place it on a Chart Sheet or do anything else you can with a regular chart.

Comment: Does this require the categories to be the same for the inner pie and outer rings?

Comment: No, you can any number of categories in either/any ring.  So, you could use the outer ring as a type of summary if you wanted.  Just change your series data in the select data dialog box.